# jQuery disable space and tab after Call

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have 2 input fields type text and textarea plus one dropdown.
On dropdown is setted up action onchange (call function - see below), simple Ajax call.

After that call I am not able to use space or tab button (in inputs) and in console there is no error or notice etc.

And ajax call return correct data and everything look find, but some keyboard buttons are disabled

Ajax call is below

```
$( "#information" ).on('change', function() {
    $.get( "/data/getData/"+ postalInput )
     .done(function (priceData) {
       priceData = JSON.parse(priceData);
        $.each(priceData, function (key, value) {
          if(value.id == fractionInput) {
            $.each(value.products, function (productId, productValue) {
              if(productValue.id == productInput) {
                price.empty();
                price.append( productValue.data );
              }
            });
          }
        });
      });
});
```

and 2 inputs like

```
<?= $this->Form->input('comment', ['class' => 'form-control', 'type' => 'textarea']); ?>
```

Dropdown

```
<?= $this->Form->input('information', [
                      'class' => 'form-control',
                      'name' => 'information',
                      'id' => 'information',
                      'label' => false,
                      'onchange' => 'getData(value)'
                    ]); ?>
```

Comment: what does `getData(value)` do? You seem to have two change events for the "information" element - one set inline, and another one set unobtrusively using jQuery, which you've shown us. Maybe the one you haven't shown is doing something extra which is causing your problem?

Comment: Same like first call function getData(id) {
  $.get("/data/getAddress/"+id)
    .done(function (data) {
        postal = $("[name='postal']").val(data[0].address);
    });
}

And I am getting that error only after changing value on dropdown. Before first change everything is ok

Comment: ok. 1. Please put the extra code into the question, not comments, then it's readable. 2. It's not "the same", as you put it, it looks like a different ajax call to me. 3. Mixing inline and unobstrusive JS events is a good recipe for a debugging headache, personally I would do them all using the same syntax, it will make maintenance easier as well as debugging. 4. This means there are _two_ ajax calls happening. Can you identify if one of them specifically causes this problem? What happens if you temporarily remove one of them?